# Inequality proof - logarithm of probabilites

Tags: probability, inequality, logarithms

I have two probabilities: $p_1$ and $p_2$, with $p_1+p_2 \leq 1$

Now I want to show that

$(p_1+p_2) \cdot \log_2 \left( \frac{p_1+p_2}{2} \right) \leq p_1 \log_2 p_1 + p_2 \log_2 p_2 $

I would be glad for an approach on how to show this...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this, now I got it!

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto 2x\log_2 x$ is convex, thus, by Jensen's inequality,
$$
(p_1  + p_2)\log_2 \left( {\frac{{p_1  + p_2 }}{2}} \right) \le  p_1 \log_2 p_1  +  p_2 \log_2 p_2 .
$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $(p_1+p_2)\log_2 \left(\frac{p_1^2+p_2^2}{p_1+p_2}\right)$ instead of $\frac{{p_1  + p_2 }}{2}\log \left( {\frac{{p_1  + p_2 }}{2}} \right)$ ?

Comment: Assuming  you're using Jensen's inequality, the middle term in your inequality chain is both incorrect and unnecessary. Try $p_1=\frac12, p_2=\frac14$ for e.g.

Comment: @Macavity Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Macavity It gives $-0.5306390622<-0.5$ with your values. I applied $$
f\left( {\frac{{p_1  + p_2 }}{2}} \right) \le \frac{1}{2}f(p_1 ) + \frac{1}{2}f(p_2 )
$$ with $f(x)=x \log_2 x$. If you multiply through by $2$, you get the inequality in question. I can modify the answer with $g(x)=2x \log_2 x$ to get the inequality inmediately.

Comment: Yes, this is correct now, I didn't notice the change. +1

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it!